# Using ggplot2 to plot ets() fitted model

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, exponential

I'm trying to do exponential smoothing to a simple time series data set and plot the fitted model plus the foretasted model, here is the code:

```
cmc
[1] 100 104 108 111 120 120 127 130 142 138 170 177 180 200 230 235 247
[18] 260 263 270 330 350 400 450 500

plot(predict(ets(cmc), n.ahead = 5))
```

[image]

Now, I need the plot to look much better using `ggplot2`. So, my specific question how to pass ETS model to `ggplot2` to plot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autoplot in stead of plot. It is a function from the package ggplot2.

```
autoplot(predict(ets(cmc), n.ahead = 5))
```

Comment: Many thanks Eddyvonb. Now as I've the base plot layer, I could customize is with ggplot various options. Cheers, Is.

Comment: @isibrahim Mark my answer as usefull then, Then it is clear your question is answered